# Error 302 returned while using WCF for Forms Authentication and Accessing Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a client and application which are set up to use the ClientFormAuthenticationMembershipProvider for authentication. On the client side, when the application boots up the system prompts for a username and password. The server is set up to accept this, and a Web Application is supposed to permit the application to work. We are in the midst of setting up a new environment, and something is not working on the server side (if we point the client at another server, it works fine). We've painstakingly gone over every detail we can think of, and the result is the same: The call to ValidateUser() throws an exception. I have downloaded a network sniffer, and under the hood I can see that a 302 message is being returned when I try to call Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd. On the server side, ProcMon registers attempts to read the Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd file from within the wwwroot/../Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd, which obviously does not exist.

### Client Side Configuration:

From our FormMain.cs (which attempts to call the provider)

```
if (!System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(null, null))
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
else
{
       DoStartUp();
....
}
```

From Our FormLogin.cs (which prompts for UserName and Pass) Note: class inherits 
IClientFormsAuthenticationCredentialsProvider

```
    public System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationCredentials GetCredentials()
    {
        if (this.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return new ClientFormsAuthenticationCredentials(
                textEditUsername.Text, textEditPassword.Text,
                false);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

From the app.config:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="http://SERVERNAME/APPNAME/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd" credentialsProvider="APPNAME.Windows.FormLogin, APPNAME.Windows" savePasswordHashLocally="False" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

### On the server side:

IIS has been configured for this application for anonymous authentication and forms authentication. (we're running IIS 7.5, .NET 4.0, Windows Server 2008 R2). We have the WCF Activation and HTTP Activation features installed on the server. The ApplicationPool is set to v4.0 Framework, 32-bit Applications not enabled, Integrated PipelineMode, most other values set to default.

The web.config file:

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
         <authenticationService enabled="true" />
         <roleService enabled="true" />
       </webServices>
     </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms name=".MDPSApp" loginUrl="~/Connect/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="600000">
       </forms>
     </authentication>
     <authorization>
       <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
     <membership defaultProvider="XYZ">
       <providers>
         <add name="XYZ" type="APPNAME.Web.Providers.MembershipProvider, APPNAME.Web" />
       </providers>
     </membership>
 <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="DisableAutoCookieManagement" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
           <security mode="None" />
         </binding>
       </wsHttpBinding>
     <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="APPNAME.Application.Web.Services.AgenceMaster.ServiceAgenceMasterBehavior">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
           <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None">
           </serviceAuthorization>
         </behavior>
         <behavior name="APPNAME.Application.Web.Services.Agence.ServiceAgenceBehavior">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
         </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
 <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="APPNAME.Application.Web.Services.AgenceMaster.ServiceAgenceMasterBehavior" name="APPNAME.Application.Web.Services.AgenceMaster.ServiceAgenceMaster">
         <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DisableAutoCookieManagement" contract="APPNAME.Services.AgenceMaster.IServiceAgenceMaster">
           <identity>
             <dns value="localhost" />
           </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       </service>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="APPNAME.Application.Web.Services.Agence.ServiceAgenceBehavior" name="APPNAME.Application.Web.Services.Agence.ServiceAgence">
         <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DisableAutoCookieManagement" contract="APPNAME.Services.Agence.IServiceAgence">
           <identity>
             <dns value="localhost" />
           </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       </service>
     </services>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
```

The APPNAME.Web.Providers.MembershipProvider class extends System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider and overrides ValidateUser(string username, string password) with custom code. This class is not getting instantiated or called during the scenario.

Something isn't configured properly on the server side, or else the server would know how to resolve the Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd call properly (and it seems to me like it's not). Any thoughts or help are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me bonkers. In FireFox - if I entered the URL for my *.aspx page that invoked my WCF REST call - everything worked fine. If I then did a shift-reload - I would get a 302 which redirected me to a non-existent forms login page.

In Safari and Chrome - no shift-reloaded needed. It would fail with the 302 on the first load.

I found the basic answer in the [Alex on ASP.NET blog](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/08/23/Basic-Authentication-with-WCF-Web-API-hosted-in-IIS-Getting-a-404-Disable-Forms-Authentication-Redirection.aspx)

Short answer: change the web.config to remove forms authentication:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```